# Would using jQuery with a content script in a chrome extension affect pages/sites already using jQuery?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So in my manifest I'm referencing a copy of jQuery along with my content script.

Since this gets appended to the end of whatever page matches my url scheme (in this case every http/https page), would this impact pages that are already referencing some version of jQuery?

Comment: No. According to [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), content scripts work in an isolated environment, so they don't affect the page's scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it wouldn't affect the host pages' scripts.

According to [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#isolated_world):

> Content scripts live in an isolated world, allowing a content script
>   to makes changes to its JavaScript environment without conflicting
>   with the page or additional content scripts